# How to change the current branch to master in Egit?

Tags: git, eclipse, egit

I want to know how to do this in Egit the eclipse plugin. This question has been asked many times for git but the answers involve some form of command language I do not have access to or know. Using the eclipse interface how can I make the test branch the master branch without taking on the original master branches flawed code (ie no merging)

[image]

Comment: "...some form of command language I do not have access to or know."  You almost certainly have access to it.  Look for an application in your operating system's menus called Terminal or Command Prompt.  Command line and GUI tools are frequently complementary and supplementary to each other, and knowing when to use one *or* the other will serve you well.

Comment: I didn't know it would use command prompt. Thought I needed some special program for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible by:

- [creating a new branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Creating_a_New_Local_Branch) on top of your current `master` (in order to not lose the HEAD of that branch)
- [resetting the `master` branch to the `test` branch](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Reset_to_specific_branch_or_tag) (the commits won't be lost, since they are referenced by the new local branch you just created)

The [OP Deco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/957245/deco) reports the appropriate process he followed:

- Created a `temp` branch alongside the `master` branch
- Right clicked and selected **`Team >'switch to' > 'master'`**
- Chose `hard reset` and select the `test` branch.

Comment: I've created a branch temp that has appeared beside the master branch. (Should this be on top instead?). I'm unsure how to go about resetting to the test branch. I right click master and my only options appears to be 'soft' 'mixed' or 'hard'. Which should I pick if any? Will I be asked later to reference the test branch?

Comment: @Deco: the documentation states: Select Team -> Reset... on a project. This opens a dialog where you can select a branch or a tag. An hard reset will change the index and your working tree to your new branch content. Make sure you have created a branch on top of master first, and that you don't have any private (ie not-versioned) files in your working tree first: they would be erased.

Comment: Thanks this worked:

*Created a temp branch alongside the master branch
*Right clicked and selected Team >'switch to' > 'master'
*Chose hard reset and test.

Comment: @Deco: excellent. i have updated my answer to include your process, for more visibility.

Comment: It didn't work all my work up until the original master node commit is gone :(
I copied the eclipse project folder before hand so all is not lost like.

Comment: @Deco but the original `master` commit is referenced now by the temp `branch`, right?

Comment: Yes it is. Not sure I see the use in this though.

Comment: Reverting to the test branch fixed things back to how they were.
Looking back at my question I may not have been clear enough. I merely wanted to rename my test branch as the master branch and remove the original master branch. It seemed abit silly having my main branch being called test.

Comment: @Devo: but the process you followed precisely renamed `test` into `master`, did it not? And the old `master` was referenced by `temp` (that you created). And you can switched back to `temp` (your old `master`) at any time. What went wrong?

Comment: It merely pushed master alongside test. Master held the same content it did before rather than tests content.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7697/discussion-between-deco-and-vonc)

Comment: Changed the steps needed. I have the feeling I've overcomplicated this and you misunderstood my question. The master branch could have been deleted as long as this didn't affect my test branch. I wanted the test branch to be my only branch and to rename it master.

Comment: @Deco: ok, so you simply renamed `test` branch into `master`?

Comment: Ye we have to delete it first. Would this have worked in the first place without the reset/ temp copy?